# How to round a value that contains exponent?

Tags: r

Using below code I'm attempting to round a value to 2 decimal places. This works as expected when exponent is not contained in value. But when exponent is contained as in :

```
> toround <- 1.1234e-2
> round(toround , 2)
```

Returned is :

```
[1] 0.01
```

When I'm expecting :

```
[1] 1.12e-2
```

How to use round function for exponent ?

Update :

```
> ?signif
> ?round
```

Appear to return same help documentation so why does `signif` function (thanks to answer by Evan Weissburg) work for exponent but `round` does not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's in exponential notation already, you know that rounding to a decimal place is the same as rounding to significant figures + 1; rounding to the hundredths place is just getting the first three significant figures.

```
> signif(1.326135235e-09, 3)
[1] 1.12e-2
```

Of course, the round function is also going to give you the correct result.

1.1234e-2 = 0.011234, so 0.01 is a perfectly correct result rounded to two decimal places. Decimal places != significant figures.

Comment: Edited the answer. If this helps, please feel free to accept/upvote. If not, clarify, since both functions "work" for exponents.